# How do I pass a view to another Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to create a Base table class in Backbone.  For each subclass the row could have a different look.  I want to pass in the View of the row.  I am trying to add it as an attribute that is set in the child class, but I keep getting and error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenerId' of undefined`.  Here is my parent class:

```
  var BaseTableView = BaseView.extend({
    template: null,
    rowView: null,
    initialize: function() {
        ...
    }
  });
```

Here is the child class where I set the row view up:

```
  var PeopleCollectionView = BaseTableView.extend({

    initialize: function() {
      this.collection = new PeopleCollection();
      this.template = peopleTemplate;
      this.itemView = PersonView;
      BaseTableView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  });
```

When I go to use the PersonView in the super class, I use it like this:

```
var view = new this.rowView({
  model: item
});
```

That is when I get the above stated error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenerId' of undefined`.  How can I fix this, or even if I should set up my hierarchy different, how should that be done?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems to me it would make more sense to have the table view instantiate a row view, rather than passing a row view to it.

Comment: I agree, but I want this table to able to render any kind of row that I pass to it.  It will hold the basic functionality for all of my tables.  Each table might have a row that is different.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you assign a value to `this.rowView`.

Comment: Then I would think about moving the logic of creating the row views to a different object. In general it's better to avoid having views tightly coupled in this fashion when it's not a parent-child relationship. It's not forbidden or anything, it just suggests there might be a better way to factor your logic.

Comment: I fiddle would help a lot